# How do I play animation using <Animator> in unity 3D (2017.3.1f1)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, animator

I'm new to unity and wish to animate a prefab. 
Here's what I've been able to achieve so far: 
[image: Fern sway]
I created an `Animator` for a prefab and created an animation sequence via the timeline editor. Though the animation plays in Unity 3D preview, but not the Game tab, I am unable to see the animation when I'm using it with Vuforia AR sdk.

I tried a similar approach with a 3D cube object I created in Unity and the animation works in Vuforia AR sdk. It even plays in preview and device.

[image: Door close]
I've searched the Unity forums, added scripts, embedded the gameObject inside another, and so on... but haven't been successful.

I'm testing it on iPad 2 running iOS 9.3

**How can I see the animation on a device?** Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you have created **animations**. This is the first step, now you need to create an **animator** for each object. This will let you control the animations.
Try to take a look here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html?_ga=2.178382372.1623961631.1530087312-1017954149.1527692494. and here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller

It is a little bit too long to explain how Animator works here. Just try to take a look at the links above, active an animation with an animator, then if you have doubts, ask :)

Comment: I've created the **animator** https://imgur.com/a/CffWsoy.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem was with the prefab. I created a new gameobject and applied the mesh and materials of the prefab and everything worked as expected. Appreciate your help @G.Threepwood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is this:

1. I created a new `gameobject` as one usually does in Unity.
2. Applied the  `Mesh Filter` , `Mesh Renderer`  and `Material` of the
   prefab
3. Added the **Animator** and created the animation sequence via the
   timeline editor

> Tested the code successfully in Unity preview as well as device. The
>   Vuforia sdk too supports the animations.